# Video upload from site to YouTube through api v3

Tags: php, video, youtube, upload, youtube-api

I have created a script using YouTube API v3 to make submitted videos from users sent directly to YouTube channel. The issue I am facing is that YouTube refuses to accept videos larger than 100mb. Is this a limitation YouTube has set or am I doing something wrong? I test the script by submitting a video of 394mb and in the end of the upload it presents the error message, though this doesn't happen when uploading videos of less than 100mb. Is there any way to manage to let upload larger videos.

I thought not to attach any script sample as first need to know the answer to this question. Thanks in advance for all answers. Suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: youtube api docs say max file size is 64MB https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert#request-body

Comment: Hello Mark. you mean 64GB instead of 64MB?

Comment: yep 64GB, can you show the script and error message?

Answer (score 0):

You can upload videos in excess of 15 minutes long. All you need to do is verify your YouTube account using the following link. Make sure you are logged into your YouTube account:

https://www.youtube.com/verify

Make sure you’re using an up-to-date version of your browser so you can upload files greater than 20GB. The maximum file size you'll be able to upload to YouTube is 128GB and the maximum duration is 11 hours.